# How deeply can you nest classes in VB Dot Net?

Tags: vb.net

I would have thought that the answer to this would be easy to find in S.O. or the internet, but I have not been successful. From what I have read so far, my current understanding is just 2 levels - the outer class and then any number of inner classes at level 2.

Comment: If you think that you can only nest one level deep then the obvious next step is to try to nest two levels deep and see whether it works. If it does, try three. If that works then I'd suggest that the limit is greater than you would ever want to practically use, given that you should almost never even nest types one level deep.

Comment: Why do you need this info?

Comment: I have a deeply nested region structure, and I was thinking about converting some of the levels to classes. Deep nesting would create the disadvantage of producing more screen clutter with long nested path references, but it would enforce much more rigour than typing free text in region names. You can collapse both classes and regions, so that factor is not relevant to my decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you would like to continue to organize your code in a series of collapsible "regions", but you would like to prevent simple plain text from being used for naming.

Classes could be used for this but unless you convert all the functions and methods to `Shared`, they won't be accessible unless these classes are instantiated first. Plus, this isn't really what classes should be used for. I would suggest using `Namespaces`.

[Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/namespaces) are used to separate the naming of functions and methods so multiple with the same name can exist within the same project without issues. They must each have their own namespace which must be specified when referencing the function/method in code (e.g. `NamespaceName.FunctionName`).